# Managing Browser History in Ajax

Tags: ajax, browser-history

I am using ajax in my site.

If a user enters a query and select a category, i will updates the page with result with ajax. I also update the url with hash value which shows query and category seperated by an `&`.

What I want is that when the browser back button is pressed I want to display the previous result without reloading. What i am getting is that the URL has the previous values, but the result is not updating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use : "[Yahoo! UI Library: Browser History Manager](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/history/)"