# Getting ajax history

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser-history, browser-state

Is it possible to get a history of all past ajax calls from the browser?

If not, are there any ffx plugins or similar that will store all your ajax request in a similar way to the normal browser history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully not. This sounds remotely evil and tends to violate [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). I mean, if this existed someone could, for instance, monitor all of a 3rd parties' activity on any web 2.0 site like gmail.

If this is for use within a single site, you want to have someone write a library that wraps the ajax calls and records a history and then get all the developers to use that instead of making ajax calls directly.

Maybe you want [this Yahoo library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/history/) as pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974186/managing-browser-history-in-ajax).

I've used Firebug to debug a site that utilized ajax calls. So there is a ffx monitoring capability.

Comment: What you say makes sense about it being evil, but on the other hand I'm sure there are probably lots of ffx extensions that would be evil if they were by default installed on all computers, but as a developer you can make an informed decision about whether the usefullness to you outweighs the risks of someone else with knowhow using your computer and getting the data. I'd say it's in the same ballpark as saving your passwords to your browser without putting all of them behind a passworded area (which, incidentally, is the ffx default behaviour for password saving).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monitor your AJAX calls, install a HTTP Proxy (e.g. [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) if on Windows) and see the AJAX calls logged there (to the network, they're normal HTTP requests/responses, only their handling in browser differs).

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler 2 and firebug work great.  I recommend firebug because you can debug the javascript making the calls as well.